# Automated Tests in Visual Studios 2013 being unpredictable?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I am writing Coded UI tests within Visual studios 2013 to automated some different tests for my company.  As I was writing these tests,  I was testing them and ensuring that they were working correctly (which they were).  After leaving one day, and coming back into work the next,  I noticed that my tests were not working as expected (as they were when i left that day). I am working on a local copy of the automated tests (so that rules out someone else breaking it) and the code version that I am testing of our software hasn't changed.

What I noticed was going wrong,  was that whenever I would double click on an item (say a menu to open a part of a program) the double click would not register.  If I record multiple times,  recording different clicks (instead of just a double click), I can get the window to pop through automation eventually.  But this is only convenient when creating new tests.

Has anyone ever noticed this happening and have a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough.... I found the issue.  Turns out that I guess I changed my mouse settings inside of windows, turning down the double click speed.  This was what was causing the double click not to register inside of the application....

Hope it helps anyone with this problem in the future